# how to use replace function in sql to replace a set of values with a single value

Tags: sql-server, function, replace

I have to replace all numbers with zero and all alphabets with * and special characters with empty string in a column in a table.

For example:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMN = replace(replace(replace(COLUMN, 1, 0), 2, 0), 3, 0)
```

But this will require so many nestings , can anyone suggest if i can mention all numbers together inside replace and all alphabets together inside replace function?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Either way the code that would do this change will have to iterate through each character of value in `COLUMN` and check it with all of the numerical characters `[0-9]`, so I wouldn't believe it's performant in any way to do that. So, sticking to `REPLACE()` would be the recommended solution. If you're using SQL Server, then [**REPLACE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) does not allow you to specify more than 1 character/set of characters to change at one time. You can't give it a list of values to iterate through to check when changing the character in `COLUMN`.

Comment: String manipulation isn't T-SQL's strongest suit - do you not have somewhere better where this re-formatting can occur (e.g. in some front-end code with a richer language, possibly with Regex support)?

Comment: Please answer Radu Gheorghiu's question: Which dbms are you using? Some dbms, such as Oracle, support regular expression replace(regexp_replace).

Comment: I think I would use 2 help tables, with a field with numbers 0-9 and the associated replacement values (and same for A-Z). Then use a recursive CTE of some design to join these tables to the actual values and replace with replacement values. I don't have the time to code it out at the moment, but thats what I'd try.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a numbers or tally table and using the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    MyCol VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('asdfssgfg022556747dsgfasdg gdgg sdasf52356'),
('gdagasgd gdsdfgdfg dasfasdf ititi 557757 0090891554534456')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT MyCol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NEWID())) AS RN
    FROM #temp
),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT RN, Number AS CharPosition, SUBSTRING(MyCol, Number, 1) as Char, 
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(MyCol, Number, 1)) = 1 THEN '0' 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(MyCol, Number, 1) LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%' THEN '*'
            ELSE ' ' END AS replacement 
    FROM CTE
    CROSS JOIN Numbers  
    WHERE Number <= LEN(MyCol)  
),
CTE3
AS
(
    SELECT 
       CTE2.RN, 
       CAST((SELECT '' + CTE3.replacement
        FROM CTE2 CTE3
        WHERE CTE2.RN = CTE3.RN
        FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE) AS varchar(max)) MyCol
    FROM CTE2 
    GROUP BY CTE2.RN
)
UPDATE CTE
    SET CTE.MyCol = C2.MyCol
FROM CTE C1
INNER JOIN CTE3 C2
    ON C1.RN = C2.RN

SELECT *
FROM #temp
```